# PHP Concatenation in ahref

Tags: php, concatenation

```
<a href="deleterow.php?del=".$rows['id'] class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>
```

Sorry for this noob question. What is wrong with my php code? I can't concatenate properly.I need to delete such that deleterow.php?del=123

Comment: Experiment till the editor/IDE give you perfect highlighting. `href="deleterow.php?del=".$rows['id']." class..`

Comment: Use `printf()` instead: `printf('<a href="deleterow.php?del=%s" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>', $rows['id']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is HTML. Not PHP. This means you need your opening and closing PHP tags as well as the echo statement for this to work:

```
<a href="deleterow.php?del=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>
```

If this was inside of a PHP echo statement, it would look similar to what you wrote:

```
echo '<a href="deleterow.php?del="'.$rows['id']'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

use it like this,you have to mention php tags

```
<a href="deleterow.php?del=<?=$rows['id']?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>
```

Comment: @Sharky: **That's not a typo** - that's a feature. It's called the short echo syntax. `<?= $foo; ?>` is equivalent to `<?php echo $foo; ?>`

Comment: That's not a typo @Sharky `<?=` is shorthand for a PHP tag and echo.

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
<a href="deleterow.php?del=<?php echo $rows['id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```